# Python - search for files, matching given name in a directory recursively

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a script to search for a file (given name) i a given directory recursively, the following format:

```
pi@pi ~ $ ./lect4_first.py /home dranie
```

Here is the complete script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
flag = False

dir_path, file_name = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
  if file_name.startswith("*") or file_name.endswith("*"):
    for filename in filenames:
      if str(filename).endswith(file_name[1:]):
        flag = True
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
      elif str(filename).startswith(file_name[:-2]):
        flag = True
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
  else:
    for filename in filenames:
      if str(filename) == file_name:
        flag = True
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))

if flag == False:
    print("'{}' not found in the '{}' directory".format(file_name, dir_path))
```

So far the script works, but if it does not find match - it prints multiple not found messages:

```
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
dranie not found in /home
```

I want to print only one not found message, if no file with the given name is found under the directory or its sub directories, but so far I am not able to figure it out...

Comment: what your "lect4_first.py" script contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what "lect4_first.py" contains?

you can try this :

```
import os
import sys
args = sys.argv
if len(args) == 3:
    directory,filename = args[1],args[2]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        if filename in files:
           f_name = os.path.join(root, filename)
           print "File exists and its path is : "+f_name
           break
    else:
        print "File does not exist"
```

Output :

```
root:~/learn/python# python file_exist.py /root test_file_exists_1.txt
File does not exist
root:~/learn/python# python file_exist.py /root test_file_exists.txt
File exists and its path is : /root/learn/python/test_file_exists.txt
```

Comment: Please check the indentations. "if flag == False" having same space indentation as "for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):" having.

Comment: Can we please use `if not flag:` here? Explicitly testing for equality with `False` or `True` is not at all Pythonic (see [PEP8 Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using == ."). Also, why the `str` wrapping for `str(file)`? It's already a `str`...

Comment: yes.. you are right. So in this case we can use "for .. else". I updated my code